# Managed VM Deployment hangs on "Copying certificates for secure access..."

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-managed-vm

I'm running the following command to deploy my Managed VMs app (on Windows 10):

```
gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --project=<PROJECT> --promote
```

The deployment starts bug hangs on the following line:

```
Copying certificates for secure access. You may be prompted to create an SSH keypair.
```

And after some time I get the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Unable to copy certificates.
```

I've already:

- Made sure that there are SSH keys in `~\.ssh\google_compute_engine`
- Tried to run with `--quiet` - same results
- Renamed ssh-term.exe to ssh.exe - same results
- Run the command as an administrator.
- Run the command with `--verbosity debug`, which prints the following line multiple times: `DEBUG: File [f] does not exist locally.`

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Found the cause! It was the project's firewall that blocked SSH by default. Fixed that and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you fixed it, I had the same problem and will use your fix.  I did happen accros a work around. By using the Container Build API to perform the build.

enter the command

```
gcloud config set app/use_cloud_build true
```

Before you

```
gcloud preview app deploy
```

Cite: https://github.com/isusanin/google-cloud-sdk/issues/533

Comment: And for others that stumble on this - we use cloud build by default now.  No more creating VMs in your project to do the build :)